# Unauthorized: new row violates row-level security policy - while uploading to supabase storage

Tags: python, supabase

I am working with a project which needs to use python to store the jpg file into supabase storage. But I am getting an error:

> Failed to upload file:
> b'{"statusCode":"403","error":"Unauthorized","message":"new row violates row-level security policy"}'

I have set up the RLS policies in Supabase project and also given necessary permissions to Supabase Storage to upload files.

Here is my code:

```py
file_path = r"C:\supabase projects\supabase auth 24-01-2024\uploads\test.jpg"
file_name = "test.jpg"  
path_on_supastorage = "uploaded_files/test.jpg"
content_type = "image/jpg"

with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
     response = supabase.storage.from_(bucket_name).upload(
                                                      file=file,
                                                      path=path_on_supastorage)

     # Check for successful upload
     if response is not None:
         print(f"Failed to upload file: {response.content}")
     else:
         print(f"File uploaded successfully: {response}")
```

What is the cause of this problem exactly?

Comment: My hunch is that your policy is incorrect. See the docs here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/security/access-control#policy-examples

Would be useful to update your question to include which policies you have created.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and my first try was to switch to `public`. However, the fix is to leave it `private` and create a policy like the following:
[image]